# C++ recursive function, calling current depth

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion

I'm writing a function for calculating integrals recursively, using the trapezoid rule. For some f(x) on the interval (a,b), the method is to calculate the area of the big trapezoid with side (b-a) and then compare it with the sum of small trapezoids formed after dividing the interval into n parts. If the difference is larger than some given error, the function is called again for each small trapezoid and the results summed. If the difference is smaller, it returns the arithmetic mean of the two values.

The function takes two parameters, a function pointer to the function which is to be integrated and a constant reference to an auxiliary structure, which contains information such as the interval (a,b), the amount of partitions, etc:

```
struct Config{
double min,max;
int partitions;
double precision;
};
```

The problem arises when I want to change the amount of partitions with each iteration, for the moment let's say just increment by one. I see no way of doing this without resorting to calling the current depth of the recurrence:

```
integrate(const Config &conf, funptr f){

double a=conf.min,b=conf.max;
int n=conf.partitions;

//calculating the trapezoid areas here

if(std::abs(bigTrapezoid-sumOfSmallTrapezoids) > conf.precision){

double s=0.;
Config configs = new Config[n];
int newpartitions = n+(calls);

for(int i=0; i < n;++i){ 
    configs[i]={ a+i*(b-a)/n , a+(i+1)*(b-a)/n , newpartitions};
    s+=integrate(configs[i],f);
}

delete [] configs;
return s; }

else{ 
return 0.5*(bigTrapezoid+sumOfSmallTrapezoids);}
}
```

The part I'm missing here is of course a way to find (calls). I have tried doing something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056348/how-can-i-find-the-depth-of-a-recursive-function-in-c) answer, but it does not work, in fact it freezes the pc until makefile kills the process. But perhaps I'm doing it wrong. I do not want to add an extra parameter to the function or an additional variable to the structure. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "find" `calls`, but you can definitely pass it yourself, like this:

```
integrate(const Config &conf, funptr f, int calls=0) {
    ...
    s+=integrate(configs[i],f, calls+1);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did this, but there's a problem. Since I want a function which only takes in two arguments (the config and function pointer), I made a seperate function, "tmpintegrate", with identical body, which additionally takes in calls as a parameter, and then made my function, "integrate", simply return tmpintegrate(config,f,0). When I add a cout to tmpintegrate to see the value of calls, it behaves strangely: starts with a 0, then 1, then a lot of 2's but there are 1's in between, as well as some 0's.

Comment: @DepeHb Note the `=0` part of the function definition (the default argument value). It lets you call the function with two or with three arguments. When you call it with two arguments, the third one is set to zero. If you print out the arguments, you will see the values of `call` printed in "depth first" order of the call tree, because the function "backtracks" to the previous level after it's done with the higher one.

Comment: I've added std::cout<<calls<<"\t"; after the line newpartitions=n+calls; After running the function, I'm getting: 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1. When I added this cout at the very beginning of the function, before the 'if', I got: 0 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 ... (a much longer list of 2's and some 1's, and a 0 at the beginning). I'm having trouble understanding what's going on here.

Comment: @DepeHb You see 0 from the top level of invocation (level A), then 1 from the next one (level B), then 2 from the lowest-level one (level C ), which does not call anything else. This goes on in a loop from level B, until the loop ends. At this point, the control goes all the way down to level A, which calls level B again (you see 1 printed), then several calls of level C in a loop (multiple 2s get printed), then a drop to level B and level A, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that 'int newpartitions = n + 1;' would be enough, no? At every recursion level, the number of partitions increases by one. Say conf.partitions starts off at 1. If the routine needs to recurse down a new level, newpartitions is 2, and you will build 2 new Config instances each with '2' as the value for partitions. Recursing down another level, newpartitions is 3, and you build 3 Configs, each with '3' as 'partitions', and so on.

The trick here is to make sure your code is robust enough to avoid infinite recursion.

By the way, it seems inefficient to me to use dynamic allocation for Config instances that have to be destroyed after the loop. Why not build a single Config instance on the stack inside the loop? Your code should run much faster that way.